# Is it possible to print a query through a form in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a menu form and adding buttons to allow a user to search through other forms. But I want to be able to print queries based on my database tables, is there any buttons or way of doing this with my menu form?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. You want to print query object? Yes, can do that, in VBA use `DoCmd.OpenQuery` - acViewNormal parameter goes direct to printer. But - Why not build a report? For report printing use `DoCmd.OpenReport`, again, acViewNormal goes direct to printer.

If you want the output filtered, query would have to use dynamic parameter in WHERE clause. This can be a popup input or reference to a control on form. For a filtered report, review [How to filter report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524980/how-do-i-open-an-ms-access-report-with-a-subset-of-the-recordsource-data/43536256#43536256)